# while calling api recursively the last call cancelled without throwing error

Tags: angular, recursion, rxjs, observable

```
addItems() {

this.addservice
  .addToCart(this.currentBatch, this.batch)
  .pipe(
    concatMap((res) => {
       if (res) {
         const success = res.filter(
            (item) => !!(item.statusCode === 'success')
          );
         if(res.length === success.length){this.addItems()}});).subscribe(res => 
         console.log(res));
             }
```

I am trying to additems with angular using service when response comes and it has all success the inside itself trying to call the additems method recursively. but the api calls getting cancelled as its calling instantly is there any way in rxjs or angular to solved this.

I need each response for each response there some operation needs to be performed .

and in network tab as well the request not showing up its getting cancelled
may because of instant calls please direct me to delay or any feasible way

Comment: I don't think requests are canceled in your case. I would guess you never `subscribe` and this logic is never executed

Comment: I have subscribe I am getting first call result

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to achieve, In any case, with rxJs recursion is usually managed via the `expand` operator. This concept is described in [this article](https://medium.com/p/ef636c9af19a) as the last example.

Comment: Actually I need to add items in batches of 10 if first batch successful i need to move to call same method which calling api here additems(). but here the calls are so instantly its getting cancelled @Picci